# Socket.io Connection

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am new to socket.io, I was trying to see what the result is on a browser. So typing the url on my browser http://api.mysite.com:8000/socket.io/1?username=xxx&secret=xxx results to:

> u7JFbWkd79ahrmMghows:60:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling

Does this mean that I'm connected to the server? Because when I provide the wrong credentials for my username and secret it outputs a **handshake error**.

Comment: `Because when I provide the wrong credentials for my username and secret it outputs a handshake error` -- Imagine that.

Comment: Yes I know that sounds pretty dumb of me to mention but I forgot to mention that even though I get a string output (which I assumed was connected.) "u7JFbWkd79ahrmMghows:60:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling" My android client says that it has an error and it is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd and go to where your node file is and type

```
node filename.js
```

then open your browser and go to

```
http:localhost:x
```

where x is the number you passed to

```
http.listen(x, function()
{
    ...
});
```

fo convenience I create a .bat file like this:

```
@echo off
echo working...
start Chrome http:localhost:8000
node server.js
```

in the project folder and create a shortcut in the desktop so I can test my code just by double clicking run.bat